# Printing a map of structs within a struct

Tags: go

I have this Router struct which has a property that holds a map of pointers to structs:

```
type Router struct {
    tree map[string]*node
}
```

Create Router:

```
func New() *Router {
    return &Router{
        make(map[string]*node),
    }
}
```

The node struct looks like this:

```
type node struct {
    path   string
    method string
}
```

I then add key:value pairs like so:

```
func (r *Router) GET(path string) {
    r.tree["GET"] = createNode(path, "GET")
    fmt.Println("GET:r:", r.tree)
}

func createNode(path string, method string) *node {
    return &node{path, "GET"}
}
```

I then try to use this package like so:

```
var server = goserve.New()

func main() {
    server.GET("/home")
    fmt.Printf("%+v", server)
}
```

The problem is that when I run the module which uses this package I see the addresses instead of the values within the node struct, which I thought the pointers should show. I'm confused because the New function returns a *Router and is shown the way I'm expecting it to be, while the createNode function returns *node (also a pointer) but doesn't show it correctly... What am I missing?

The result:

```
GET:r: map[GET:0xc00000e2e0]
&{tree:map[GET:0xc00000e2e0]}%
```

Note that I'm using two different print methods, neither of which work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `String()` method for your `Router`. This is in order to implement the [Stringer](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17) interface.

For example:

```golang
func (r *Router) String() string {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    buf.WriteString("Router (\n")
    for _, v := range r.tree {
        fmt.Fprintf(buf, "\t%s: %s\n", v.method, v.path)
    }
    buf.WriteString(")")
    return buf.String()
}
```

Runnable example: https://play.golang.org/p/qgcUkxrAdyd

Note that you have issues with your router as adding multiple `GET`s causes them to be overridden.

Comment: Giving it try now. I fixed the other issue right after posting, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: The `fmt` package calls the `String` method. From the link I posted: "The fmt package (and many others) look for this interface to print values." The only reason you wouldn't add a `String` method to the `node` type instead is because `fmt` doesn't call it past depth 1.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, under the hood the `fmt` package looks for a `String` method which defines how it should print something. In my case that didn't exist so it resorted to the default which was the memory address. Now that it has it, it knows what to do which is write it to the buffer and return that buffer as a string?

Answer (score 0):

L Lawliet's answer is correct and provides the desired result. However, looking through the `byte` package docs suggests that you should use the `strings` `Builder` type for better efficiency.

The code would look like this:

```
func (r *Router) String() string {
    b := &strings.Builder{}
    b.WriteString("Router: {\n")
    for _, v := range r.tree {
        fmt.Fprintf(b, "\t%s: %s\n", v.method, v.path)
    }
    b.WriteString("}")
    return b.String()
}
```

The docs can be found here:
https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder
https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.String

If I'm miss-understanding this please let me know